# Need help installing a 32bit app on my 11.10 64bit. Multi-arch not working

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

I thought the 11.10 was supposed to have a multi architecture support but installing a 32bit .deb gives me a 'wrong architecture' error. What do I need to do to install this deb?

```
CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.1-Kasapa-i386-ubuntu.deb
```

Here is the output when I try to force the installation through the force architecture command

```
Selecting previously deselected package crossplatformui:i386.
(Reading database ... 186238 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking crossplatformui:i386 (from CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.1-Kasapa-i386-ubuntu.deb) ...
Setting up crossplatformui:i386 (2.1.1) ...
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service acpid restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop acpid ; start acpid. The restart(8) utility is also available.
acpid stop/waiting
acpid start/running, process 2569
package libqtgui4 exist
QT_VERSION = 4
make -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build M=/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.o
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:34:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui:i386 (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui:i386
```

Can someone help?

Comment: have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29665/apt-get-32-bit-package-on-amd64-ubuntu-installation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a header was not found due to multi-arch changes on that. Extract the deb-file, apply fixes, rebuild the deb and install it:

1. Change to the directory containing the debfile.
2. Create a temporary directory for fixing stuff and move into it (the directory name was randomly chosen here):

   ```
   mkdir kasapa-deb && cd kasapa-deb
   ```
3. Extract the control and installation files:

   ```
   dpkg --control CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.1-Kasapa-i386-ubuntu.deb
   dpkg --extract CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.1-Kasapa-i386-ubuntu.deb .
   ```
4. Apply the fixes by editing `DEBIAN/postinst`. If a line with `CFLAGS +=` does not already exists, insert (e.g. after the first commented lines, lines with leading `#`):

   ```
   CFLAGS += -I/usr/include/$(shell dpkg-architecture -qDEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH)
   ```

   If it does already exist, simply append the `-I ...` part to the existing `CFLAGS` line (separated with a space)
5. While you're at it, you can make the package appear as a 64-bit one, **providing** that the files in the package are really 64-bit. Edit `DEBIAN/control` and change `Architecture: i386` to `Architecture: amd64`.
6. Rebuild the package, creating a new file in the parent directory:

   ```
   dpkg-deb -b . ..
   ```
7. Install the new package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ../[name of the package that was just created].deb
   ```
8. You can remove the temporary directory now.

This is theoretically supposed to work. If the package contains binaries which are made for 32-bit, you need to install the 32-bit dependencies as well, like `libc6`:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

Comment: I have successfully built the amd64 deb with your help now when i try installing the package terminal reports that i have an existing version on the system( the one i used the force architecture command to install). How do i remove the previously installed files and install my deb?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge crossplatformui:i386`.

Comment: I have given up installing this package but your answer has been really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it via the terminal.

You open up the terminal and should be in you home folder

```
user@computer:~$
```

type `cd Downloads` (or the folder your package is in) and you should be in the download folder

```
user@computer:~/Downloads$
```

Then type

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.1-Kasapa-i386-ubuntu.deb
```

and the package should be installed without checking for architecture.

You can also have a look [here](http://japopo.tumblr.com/) (scroll down to Espresso Modem), maybe that helps you out. But in general it's done like I wrote.

Comment: i didn't want to go by this method as i did that in 11.04 and it didn't work out so i will try it again and report. Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: check the output of this command in the edited question