# Installing 32-bit libraries on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: software-installation

Basically simple question: is it possible to install 32-bit libraries on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box? I need to run an app which requires 32-bit support.

The information found on this forum is all about older versions, and I as not able to filter out all static.

If those libraries are still supported, how do I then get those installed on my box? So far what I tried only led to errors like "Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate" or "Failed to fetch".

Comment: Well, those threads are all about previous versions. I'm looking for the 14.04 LTS approach. Haven't found THE answer yet.

Comment: Is all the same. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 12):

It appeared that the following commands were working for me:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

I found it here:
[How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-android-sdk-in-ubuntu-64-bits)

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` was the extra command I needed to access i386 libraries

Answer (score 6):

You can install 32 bits package with this command: `sudo apt-get install package:i386`
I think you have to begin with this one: `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386`