# error You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6

Tags: software-installation, steam

I have a 64bit ARM processor (Raspberry Pi 4) and i don't know why i get this message. can somebody please help me?

Comment: Can you please post the exact error messages ?

Comment: You can install the required 32-bit libraries as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/524647/1001338). Replace the package names with your own ones.

Comment: well i am using a rasberry pi 4.

Comment: and my dad said that it won't work on a rasberry pi 4 so i am going to flash it back to normal.

Comment: Even though you have a Raspberry Pi 4 which has 4x ARM Cortex-A72 cores, Raspbian (non-beta), and many OSes tailored for the Raspberry Pi have a 32-bit user-space. I have had this error with ```Raspbian X Nighthawk``` and Steam seemed to work just fine. It too had a 32-bit user space, so not all the Steam features are supported.

Comment: You have provided no OS/release details

Comment: To my knowledge Steam doesn't *support* the ARM chipset, and wants x86 support - arm 32bit isn't x86 compatible normally...

Comment: @Thomas Ward Yes, Steam is classically an x86 app. May be 64-bit for Mac compatibility nowadays (no idea), and Linux requires 64-bit support, but Windows has been 32-bit. Edit: correction (64-bit Linux).