# schroot and apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, arm

This a question to clarify my different searching.

I have an Arm64, to be precise aarch64. Which is missing certain number of packages. I tried building from source but did not manage for all.

Therefore I read that I could install packages for armhf (arm32), and run them in my system, using schroot.

This seemed to work and the apt-get found the package I wanted!

But installing it, depends on alot of packages that I allready installed on aarch64.

## Update

[this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29665/how-do-i-apt-get-a-32-bit-package-on-a-64-bit-installation) tells that it should be possible to run 32 on 64, specifically stated for non-arm, so I guess this is transferable to ARM.

It also suggests that:

`sudo apt-get install package:armhf` should be solution however it does not seem like it finds that packages? Even when on the web they say they have armhf packages.

## question

Is it possible to use armhf packages, on arm64?

Is it possible to "update" apt-get in schroot, such that it knows the packages installed for arm64?

Comment: Would you try `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf` to enable multiarch repositories then  `sudo apt-get update` to update software list.

Comment: @Sneetsher seems to work as wanted. Only issue is now alot of dependencies are stuck not understanding which version they should use it seem, and purging is not possible. I will return next week with an update. THANKS